# Return values based matching times and days

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm attempting to match up results of Employees schedules vs Reporting schedules. I need to output a report that shows all reports and who was assigned to them. The place I'm having the trouble is based on the day of week.

My ReportSchedule table looks something like this:

```
╔══════════════╦══════════════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦════╗
║ ReportID     ║ Time         ║ M    ║ Tu   ║ W    ║ Th   ║ F    ║ Sa   ║ Su ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬════╣
║ 1001         ║ 06:18:00     ║ 1    ║ 1    ║ 1    ║ 1    ║ 1    ║ 0    ║  0 ║
║ 1002         ║ 06:48:00     ║ 0    ║ 0    ║ 0    ║ 0    ║ 0    ║ 1    ║  1 ║
║ 1003         ║ 07:18:00     ║ 1    ║ 1    ║ 1    ║ 1    ║ 1    ║ 1    ║  1 ║
╚══════════════╩══════════════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩════╝
```

My EmployeesSchedule table looks something like this:

```
╔════════════╦══════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦═══╦════╦═══╦════╦═══╦════╦════╗
║ EmployeeID ║ ReportID ║ ReportStart ║ ReportEnd ║ M ║ Tu ║ W ║ Th ║ F ║ Sa ║ Su ║  
╠════════════╬══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═══╬════╬═══╬════╬═══╬════╬════╣
║      22001 ║     1001 ║ 05:00:00    ║ 12:00:00  ║ 1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║  0 ║  0 ║  
║      22001 ║     1002 ║ 05:00:00    ║ 12:00:00  ║ 1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║  0 ║  0 ║  
║      22001 ║     1003 ║ 05:00:00    ║ 12:00:00  ║ 1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║  0 ║  0 ║  
║      22002 ║     1001 ║ 06:00:00    ║ 14:00:00  ║ 0 ║  0 ║ 0 ║  0 ║ 0 ║  1 ║  1 ║  
║      22002 ║     1002 ║ 06:00:00    ║ 14:00:00  ║ 0 ║  0 ║ 0 ║  0 ║ 0 ║  1 ║  1 ║  
║      22002 ║     1003 ║ 06:00:00    ║ 14:00:00  ║ 0 ║  0 ║ 0 ║  0 ║ 0 ║  1 ║  1 ║  
╚════════════╩══════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩═══╩════╩═══╩════╩═══╩════╩════╝
```

What I would need based on the above is something like this:

```
╔════════════╦══════════╦══════════╦═══╦════╦═══╦════╦═══╦════╦════╗
║ EmployeeID ║ ReportID ║   Time   ║ M ║ Tu ║ W ║ Th ║ F ║ Sa ║ Su ║
╠════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══╬════╬═══╬════╬═══╬════╬════╣
║      22001 ║     1001 ║ 06:18:00 ║ 1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║  0 ║  0 ║
║      22002 ║     1002 ║ 06:48:00 ║ 0 ║  0 ║ 0 ║  0 ║ 0 ║  1 ║  1 ║
║      22001 ║     1003 ║ 07:18:00 ║ 1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║  0 ║  0 ║
║      22002 ║     1003 ║ 07:18:00 ║ 0 ║  0 ║ 0 ║  0 ║ 0 ║  1 ║  1 ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩══════════╩═══╩════╩═══╩════╩═══╩════╩════╝
```

The query I was running is below:

```
SELECT EmployeeSchedule.EmployeeID, ReportSchedule.ReportID, ReportSchedule.Time, 
    ReportSchedule.M, ReportSchedule.Tu, ReportSchedule.W, ReportSchedule.Th, ReportSchedule.F, ReportSchedule.Sa, ReportSchedule.Su
FROM ReportSchedule
    INNER JOIN EmployeeSchedule on ReportSchedule.ReportID = EmployeeSchedule.ReportID
WHERE (
        ReportSchedule.Time > EmployeeSchedule.ReportStart AND 
        ReportSchedule.Time < EmployeeSchedule.ReportEnd AND
        (
            (ReportSchedule.M=1) AND (ReportSchedule.M = EmployeeSchedule.M) OR 
            (ReportSchedule.Tu=1) AND (ReportSchedule.Tu = EmployeeSchedule.Tu) OR 
            (ReportSchedule.W=1) AND (ReportSchedule.W = EmployeeSchedule.W) OR 
            (ReportSchedule.Th=1) AND (ReportSchedule.Th = EmployeeSchedule.Th) OR 
            (ReportSchedule.F=1) AND (ReportSchedule.F = EmployeeSchedule.F) OR 
            (ReportSchedule.Sa=1) AND (ReportSchedule.Sa = EmployeeSchedule.Sa) OR 
            (ReportSchedule.Su=1) AND (ReportSchedule.Su = EmployeeSchedule.Su)
        )
    )
```

The results returned by this are not what I'm looking for as its not filtering out the days of the week where an employee doesn't do a report. Here is what is being returned:

```
╔════════════╦══════════╦══════════╦═══╦════╦═══╦════╦═══╦════╦════╗
║ EmployeeID ║ ReportID ║   Time   ║ M ║ Tu ║ W ║ Th ║ F ║ Sa ║ Su ║
╠════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══╬════╬═══╬════╬═══╬════╬════╣
║      22001 ║     1001 ║ 06:18:00 ║ 1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║  0 ║  0 ║
║      22002 ║     1002 ║ 06:48:00 ║ 0 ║  0 ║ 0 ║  0 ║ 0 ║  1 ║  1 ║
║      22001 ║     1003 ║ 07:18:00 ║ 1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║  1 ║  1 ║
║      22002 ║     1003 ║ 07:18:00 ║ 1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║  1 ║  1 ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩══════════╩═══╩════╩═══╩════╩═══╩════╩════╝
```

What do I need to do to get the results I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I inserted the original query into a temp table, then run the following and get the needed data returned.

```
SELECT #Temp.EmployeeID, #Temp.ReportID, #Temp.Time, 
    CASE WHEN EmployeeSchedule.M = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS M,
    CASE WHEN EmployeeSchedule.Tu = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Tu,
    CASE WHEN EmployeeSchedule.W = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS W,
    CASE WHEN EmployeeSchedule.Th = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Th,
    CASE WHEN EmployeeSchedule.F = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS F,
    CASE WHEN EmployeeSchedule.Sa = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Sa,
    CASE WHEN EmployeeSchedule.Su = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Su
FROM #Temp
    INNER JOIN EmployeeSchedule on #Temp.ReportID = EmployeeSchedule.ReportID
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a where clause where report <> 0? Also, you have the report id = report id in the where statement - I'm not sure that's necessary as that's your join clause. Still new to sql, so I'm not sure.

Comment: You're correct on the ReportID=ReportD, that was an oversight as I was writing the post here. I've edited my original post accordingly.  Adding report <> 0 though doesn't resolve the issue as its already returning only valid report numbers, the issue is that all valid days for a given report is shown for all employees, where as it should be showing only the days that employee was assigned to the report.

Comment: Well if the days are columns, and the query finds a row where the where clause is true, then it's going to return the row where the clause is true, no? Maybe I'm not understanding what you're asking for, sorry.